# Sum weighted nodes between nodes in a DAG efficiently

Tags: algorithms, graphs, divide-and-conquer

Suppose we have a directed acyclic graph $G=(V,E)$, such that all vertices have a addible weight, e.g. there is a function $weight: V \to \mathbb{R} $. Moreover two vertices $v,w \in V$ are given and we write $G_{v,w}$ for the subgraph of $G$ that consists of all vertices and path between $v$ and $w$, both included.

The task is to compute the sum of the weight $weight(u)$ of all vertices $u \in G_{v,w}$. 
In addition if $v'$ and $w'$ are two vertices, with $G_{v,w}\subset G_{v',w'}$, then the computation on $G_{v,w}$ should not be repeated (kind of divide and conquer, but on subgraphs) to compute the weight of $G_{v',w'}$.

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you interested in the sum of weights of all edges in $G_{v,w}$ with $v$ and $w$ given in input? You used $w$ to mean both the weight function and a vertex.

Comment: You are right. I changed that in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

A vertex $z$ is "between $v$ and $w$" in $G$ (that is there is a path in $G$ from $v$ to $w$ that traverses $z$) if and only if both the following conditions are true: 1) there is a path from $v$ to $z$ in $G$; and 2) there is a path from $w$ to $z$ in $\overline{G}$, where  $\overline{G}$ is the graph obtained from $G$ by reversing its edges.

Using any standard visit algorithm you can compute the set $A$ of vertices reachable from $v$ in $G$ and the set $B$ of vertices reachable from $w$ in $\overline{G}$.

Then you can compute $C = A \cap B$ and find the desired quantity as $\sum_{z \in C} \text{weight}(z)$. Each of the above steps can be performed in linear time.

Comment: Does it satisfy the requirement on $G_{v,w}\subset G_{v',w'}$?

Comment: As you can see I never compute (the sum of weights of) $G_{v', w'}$ for $v' \neq v'$ or $w' \neq w$. In fact I don't understand how that restriction is supposed to make things harder.

Comment: It is a question of efficiency. If additional vertices appear in the graph, the already done work should not be computed again.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what the **exact** requirement is. If the input to your problem is just $G$, $v$, and $w$ and you need to compute the sum of the weights of the vertices "between" $v$ and $w$ then my solution never repeats any computation. If your problem is different you should clarify it. For example (but I'm just speculating at this point), **after** having reported the weight of $G_{v,w}$, you could be given another pair of vertices $v', w'$ such that $G_{v,w} \subset G_{v',w'}$ and you could wand to solve the problem for $v', w'$ as well (without recomputing the previous sum).

Comment: If this is what you want, then when you are computing the answer for the first pair $v,w$ you can just identify all the vertices in $C$ into a single vertex $y$ with weight $\sum_{z \in C} \text{weight(z)}$. Let $G'$ be the resulting graph. When you receive the second pair $v', w'$ you can again solve the problem as described in my answer but using $G'$ instead of $G$. In this way $\sum_{z \in C} \text{weight(z)}$ is never recomputed. This can be repeated. (to report the sum for a third pair $v'',w''$ with $G_{v',w'} \subset G_{v'',w''}$, etc. No sum is recomputed.).